# Clean way to access a nested data structure

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, dereference

I have a segment of code that, although it works, does not look like a clean way to do things.

I build the structure using:

```
 foreach my $n (@node_list)
 {
    chomp ($n);

    foreach my $c (@cpes)
    {
            my @returned; #Interfaces to CPEs with MED settings
            my @creturned; #General Customer Interfaces

            my ($cust) = $c =~ /([a-zA-Z]+)[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+/s;
            print "\n\t\tCustomer is $cust\n";

            chomp($c);
            $c = uc $c;
            my ($search) = $c;

            (@returned) = `cat /curr/$n | grep "$search"`;
            if (@returned)
            {
                    my $cust_match = 'interface \"' . $cust;
                    (@creturned) = `cat /curr/$n | egrep -i "$cust_match" | grep -v "$search"`;

            }
            if (@creturned)   #Have we found other CPEs on the same router
            {
                    my ($nf) = $n =~ /([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).cfg/s;

                    my (@interfaces) = map { /([A-Z0-9_]+)/s } @creturned;
                    @interfaces = uniq(@interfaces);

                    unshift  (@interfaces, $c);
                    push (@new_out, {$nf => {$cust => [@interfaces]}});
            }

    }
```

This will return:

```
 $VAR1 = [
        {
          'router-xx-xx' => {
                              '50000' => [
                                               [
                                                 'THXXXXVF_NLXXXX40_1121_2',
                                                 '10x.xx.x.50'
                                               ],
                                               [
                                                 'THXXXPVF_NLXXXX66_1121_1',
                                                 '10x.xx.x.70'
                                               ],
                                               [
                                                 'THXXXXVF_NLXXXX67_1121_2',
                                                 '10x.xx.x.78'
                                               ],

                            }
        },
```

Each router can have a number of VPRNs and each VPRN can contain multiple interfaces. In the example above I've shown one router with one VPRN.

However, when it comes to accessing elements in the above, I've written the following convoluted (but working) code:

```
  foreach my $candidate (@nodes)
    {
            my %node = %{ $candidate };

            foreach my $n (keys %node)
            {
                    print "\nRouter is $n\n";

                    foreach my $cust (keys %{ $node{$n} })
                    {
                            print "Customer on $n is \n" . Dumper $cust;
                            my @intlist = @{$node{$n}{$cust}};

                            my $med_cpe = $intlist[0];      #the CPE that was used to find node

                            {truncated}
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you want us to review your code, please ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: What are `$rid`, `$$cpe`, and `$dpe`? If they are relevant then include the code that defines them, if they are not then remove references to them.

Comment: Removed the bits requested. This is not a code review its more of a "need a  cleaner more readable way to do this" as I appear to be building these kind of structures more frequently.

Comment: The first cat is necessary to find a node that has that CPE ($c) attached to it. If it does then the second cat is to pull out a list of other CPEs for that customer on that same node. If done in one shot it would match general CPEs on nodes that do not have BGP MED set.

Comment: Tip: `$cust` is already a scalar. No need to pass a reference to it to `Dumper`. Replacing `Dumper(\$cust)` with `Dumper($cust)` for cleaner/clearer output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain exactly what you find "convoluted" about the traversal code, but you have made it unnecessarily complex by duplicating data into `@intlist` and `%node`. The excessive and inconsistent indentation also makes it ungainly

I would write something closer to this

```
for my $node ( @nodes ) {

    for my $n ( keys %$node ) {

        print "\nRouter is $n\n";

        for my $cust ( keys %{ $node->{$n} } ) {

            print "Customer on $n is \n" . Dumper \$cust;

            my $med_cpe = $node->{$n}{$cust}[0];
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need the values of `$node` and `$n` except to access `$med_cpe` then you don't need a nested data structure at all: a simple array is fine. On the face of it, an array like this will do what you need

```
[
    [
        'router-xx-xx',
        '50000',
        'THXXXXVF_NLXXXX40_1121_2',
        '10x.xx.x.50',
    ],
    [
        'router-xx-xx',
        '50000',
        'THXXXPVF_NLXXXX66_1121_1',
        '10x.xx.x.70',
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: That looks a little leaner. The structure of the data will need to stay the same for now. Thank you Borodin

Comment: @Taranasaur: There always needs to be as many `for` loops as there are levels to your data structure; there's no way around that.

Comment: @Taranasaur: Sorry, there were a couple of bugs. See my fixed answer.

Comment: my repeating experiences and your solution has made it crystal clear. It's a niggling annoyance that you can create structures with such ease but then to get back at the data it's a grind! I'm relatively new to Perl and have to bash out scripts in a matter of hours so stumble forwards best I can. Need a good book on Perl

Comment: @Taranasaur: I highly recommend the biblical [*"Camel Book"*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do). It's very digestable, and if you read it through repeatedly from beginning to end, performing experiments where necessary to confirm your knowledge, then you will realise that you understand more and more each time. It's a far better way to learn than reading up on the new bits you need for each program, which results in very patchy knowledge.

Comment: I don't see that your code to build the structure is at all simple. Ultimately you really should be writing Perl code to do the `grep` operations.